# Microsoft Access Check in and out

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm making a database up Microsoft Access to help simplify my job, but I'm relatively inexperienced with it, so I need some help. I'm running Access 2016.

I have a database set up for when students enter the IT Office seeking help, which essentially just records when they enter and what they're here for. So I've put a form on, which lets you enter your information, like your student number, what your problem is, and what your laptop number is. The date and time of your entry are automatically generated by the system clock. The student then presses "Check In", which creates a record based on the information they've just entered to keep track of problems. So here's my question, how would I conveniently give them an option to check back out? I need some way to update the record they've just made, without giving them access to all of the other transactions. I managed to make a list box which makes a list of all the student numbers of people who've entered today, but I'm unsure how to set the check out time of the student when they leave.

Hopefully I've explained that well enough. If you need me to clarify, please pop in a comment.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is a very broad question. If you're looking for advice on a user interface, you can try https://ux.stackexchange.com/, but note you need a clearly defined question there also. Since there are loads of ways to go about this, and you don't have a clear programming issue, this is not a good question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Have a form with buttons "Check In" and "Check Out". Check In opens form for them to create record. Check Out has code requesting StudentNumber or opens form with the listbox for them to choose from. Code runs an UPDATE sql action to update the Out field with the date/time

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth
It's not user interface advice, I'm more looking for how I would actually go about implementing a Check Out function. I've managed to make a list of all students which have checked in today, but I'm unsure how to register their clicks on this list as selecting a username. Like, if a student clicks on their student number in the list, and then clicks check out, how would I actually update the table? I don't know how a button would check which item is selected in the list to update the table. Do I need to use Visual Basic for this?

Comment: Well, then there are still many ways to go about it. VBA code is the most obvious choice, but the exact implementation varies, and macros + queries is also a valid way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

For users to re-find their record, and not be able to look thru other records - you essentially just need an ID field that they type in; and use that as the query basis for the look up.  Possibly the name they entered could be used if you aren't passing out trouble ticket IDs.

The check out info really doesn't have to be a separate table.  It can all be part of the same record as the original check in.  You can have a separate check out time stamp field that gets populated by a check out button.

The check in and check out may look like separate sides to user - with separate forms that is fine - but behind the scenes I see no reason to have separate tables.  keep it simple.

www.CahabaData.com